# How do I achieve this hover linear wipe transition in CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I should also mention that I can't just put one image on top of the other since I'll also work with transparent images.
[linear wipe preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CgkJ.gif)

Comment: Share your code or you just want that

Comment: I just need an example as a reference @ash

Comment: But for that as much as I know and I can understand your needs. jQuery can help you

Comment: Sure I can give jquery a shot, can you share an example?

Comment: ok wait a minute or 3,4

Answer (score 0):

You don't need js nor external libraries for this particular effect at all.

```css
.container{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
border: 2px solid red;
}

.underlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.container:hover .overlay{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='underlay'></div>
  <div class='overlay'></div>
</div>
```